# Error while getting Google Drive permissions ID (Drive REST API, getIdForEmail)

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-drive-api, sails.js

I am building an application in [SailsJS](http://sailsjs.org) (v0.11) & [Angular](https://angularjs.org) (v1.4.4) based on the Google API's.

I am using the [Google Drive NodeJS library](https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/) to retrieve the [permission ID](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/getIdForEmail) of a user. Unfortunately it does not work. I am using the following code to retrieve the permissions ID.

```
sails.googleDrive.permissions.getIdForEmail({
    email: user.email
}, function(error, permissions) {
    console.log(error);
});
```

The code gives me the following output.

```
{
    [
        Error: LoginRequired
    ]
    code: 401,
    errors: [
        {
            domain: 'global',
            reason: 'required',
            message: 'Login Required',
            locationType: 'header',
            location: 'Authorization'
        }
    ]
}
```

All the other things in my application, like retrieving files and inserting permissions on files and folders work like expected. The `getIdForEmail` is the only call that gives this error.

I am initializing the Google API's like below.

```
// Google
var clientId = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com';
var clientSecret = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
var redirectUrl = 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/user/login/oauth2callback';

sails.google = require('googleapis');
sails.googleAuth = new sails.google.auth.OAuth2(clientId, clientSecret, redirectUrl);
sails.googlePlus = sails.google.plus('v1');
sails.googleCalendar = sails.google.calendar('v3');
sails.googleDrive = sails.google.drive('v2');
```

I hope somebody can help me out here :)